# How do I set Nautilus as default file manager in Elementary OS

Tags: ubuntu, files, nautilus, elementary-os

Elementary OS uses a program called [files](http://elementaryos.org/journal/marlin-dead-long-live-files/) as the default file manager.

I would like to use Nautilus as my default file manager as used in Ubuntu 12.04 . I have GNOME Nautilus 3.4.2 installed on my machine, but however the only way to invoke this file manager is using the terminal. How do I set this as default and have an icon in the application menu.

The Desktop Entry, `nautilus.desktop` looks like this.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Exec=nautilus %U
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.4.2
Actions=Window;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=nautilus
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Edit: Updated the Desktop entry to get answer for adding Nautilus to Application menu.

Comment: Try this: http://elementaryforum.org/forum/support-assistance/support-assistance/2871-how-to-install-nautilus-or-other-file-managers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

eOS should support `xdg-mime` command which you can use to change the default file manager. Try these commands:

```
# what's the current default file manager?
xdg-mime query default inode/directory

# set nautilus as a default file manager
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Comment: Thanks. The second command did set nautilus as default file manager. However, when I click on the _Files_ icon, the default file manager changes to pantheon ( I know this by running the first command you mentioned. And how can I add an icon in Application menu for Nautilus ?

Comment: I have updated the Desktop entry for nautilus, should I be making any changes here ?

Answer (score 0):

To put the icon on the dock:

```
$ xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Then:

```
$ nautilus
```

Once Nautilus opens, put the icon on the dock and delete the phanteaom icon.